# How do I use an anchor and a hyperlink on the same text?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

So I have a box on the right side of the page which when clicked on different titles will take to different news articles on the page though I also have it so when articles within the website titles are clicked upon on the page that they will be taken to the source. At the moment though neither are working what is going wrong?

html

```
<a name="Anchor1"><a href="http://newsarticle.com">News Article</a></a>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Go to an anchor on a different page?

Comment: @DSG HTML5 isn't standard. And besides that, I think nesting an anchor within an anchor is/should be invalid anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Use id attribute inside the link to have the same effect as name attribute

```
<a id="Anchor1" href="http://newsarticle.com">News Article</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an `id` attribute to the link:

```
<a id="foo" href="http://newsarticle.com">News Article</a>
```

Then link to it like this:

```
<a href="#foo">link to foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Nested `<a>` elements are forbidden in HTML syntax.
- Browsers effectively enforce this restriction in their parsing rules.

Example:

if you have a link ,

```
 <a href="a.html">a<a href="b.html">b</a>c</a>
```

Browsers will parse it as,

```
<a href="a.html">a</a> <a href="b.html">b</a> c
```

Reference: [**Nested links are illegal.**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)